# How to make an object look at its forward vector?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a level, player capsule and enemy cube. The cube can rotate towards the player and shoot at him.
The problem is, it shoots from any distance, no matter where is the player. So i decided to make viewcones, and have no idea how to code that(i need cube script to count the distance to player)

Exact problem is "how to make enemy only see in front of him?", because i can't multiply vector3 by transform.forward. Are there any other methods to do that?

Comment: `how to make enemy only see in front of him?` `i need cube script to count the distance to player` is your question about the distance or the orientation? The distance can be calculated no matter the orientation of the object

Comment: Making an object detect that which is in front be it 2d or 3d is more than adequately documented on the internet. What specifically didnt work for you?

Comment: You can e.g. simply shoot a [`Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) or also use a bigger shape like a [`BoxCast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.BoxCast.html) .. or you could also calculate it using `Vector3.Distance` as a first filter and check if it is looking into the correct direction using e.g. `if(Vector3.Angle(transform.forward, player.position - transform.position) < 20)` so simply check if your enemy forward direction is within a certain threshold regarding the vector towards the player

Comment: @derHugo thanks, that `Vector3.Angle` thing was what i needed. Now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

some time ago i have found this extension for Cone Raycasts

[cone raycast repo](https://github.com/walterellisfun/ConeCast)

Hopefully it will help you solve your issue.
There is even a example .cs file in repo , so there should be no issue making it work.

If u dont want to extend Unity's Physics , u can still make a cone shaped object in Blender or any other 3D software and disable mesh renderer and detect collision and then raycast towards the target.
Hope i was helpful , have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate it yourself like using [`Vector3.Distance`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) as a first filter and then check if the angle between enemy's `transform.forward` direction compared to the vector between itself and the player lies within a certain  threashold

```c#
public Transform player;
public float range = 1;
public float angleRange = 20;

private void Awake ()
{
     // However you would find the player on runtime e.g.
     if(!player) player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.position) < range)
    {
        if(Vector3.Angle(transform.forward, player.position - transform.position) < angleRange)
        {
            Debug.Log("I can see you!", this);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively to having only one player reference you could also use a [`Physics.OverlapSphere`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html) in order to get everything within the radius and check again like

```c#
private void Update()
{
    var hits = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, range)
    foreach(var hit in hits)
    {
        // First ignore yourself!
        if(hit.gameObject == gameObject) continue;

        if(Vector3.Angle(transform.forward, hit.position - transform.position) < angleRange)
        {
            Debug.Log($"I am seeing {hit.name} !", this);
        }
    }
}
```

This second solution requires `Collider`s on your objects of course.